# How to load babel-plugin-react-intl using babel-loader?

Tags: react-intl, babel-plugin-react-intl

I recently initialized a react app using create-react-app.
I ejected the app and I now have all the files exported to my main directory.
This set up creates a babel.dev.js instead of using .babelrc (it uses babel-loader).

I am trying to figure out how do I configure react-intl and babel-plugin-react-intl without the .babelrc file.

The documentation says .babelrc is recommended

#### Via .babelrc (Recommended)

.babelrc

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["react-intl", {
        "messagesDir": "./build/messages/"
    }]
  ]
}
```

What is the syntax to have this behavior with babel-loader? Right now the plugins in babel.dev.js look like this:

```
plugins: [
  // class { handleClick = () => { } }
  require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-class-properties'),
  // { ...todo, completed: true }
  require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread'),
  // function* () { yield 42; yield 43; }
  [require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-regenerator'), {
    // Async functions are converted to generators by babel-preset-latest
    async: false
  }],
  // Polyfills the runtime needed for async/await and generators
  [require.resolve('babel-plugin-transform-runtime'), {
    helpers: false,
    polyfill: false,
    regenerator: true,
    // Resolve the Babel runtime relative to the config.
    // You can safely remove this after ejecting:
    moduleName: path.dirname(require.resolve('babel-runtime/package'))
  }]
]
```

My components currently have the strings defined as follows:

```
const messages = defineMessages({
  summaryTitle: {
    "id": "checkout.section.title.summary",
    "description": "Summary Section Title",
    "defaultMessage": "Summary"
  },
  shippingTitle: {
    "id": "checkout.section.title.shipping",
    "description": "Shipping Section Title",
    "defaultMessage": "Shipping"
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the babel-plugin-react-intl to your plugins array like this:

```
plugins: [
    ..., // some plugins here
    [require.resolve('babel-plugin-react-intl'), { messageDir: "./build/messages"}]
]
```

This will load the plugin passing the messageDir as an option to it.

Comment: @pablomiranda Fantastic, it worked like a charm! Muito Obrigada!